# Kafka Error while creating ACLs NoAuth for /kafka-acl/TransactionalId

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to setup my very first Kafka cluster using confluent 6.0.1 community edition.
I have three zookeeper and three kafka nodes.
Three server nodes are:

1. kafkaserver1
2. kafkaserver2
3. kafkaserver3

Each node runs zookeeper and kafka services.
Authentication is: SASL_SSL using SCRAM-SHA-256

Both zookeeper and kafka services seems to be working fine but when I try to assign ACLs, I get the following error:

```
Error while executing ACL command: KeeperErrorCode = NoAuth for /kafka-acl/TransactionalId
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoAuthException: KeeperErrorCode = NoAuth for /kafka-acl/TransactionalId
        at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:120)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:54)
        at kafka.zookeeper.AsyncResponse.maybeThrow(ZooKeeperClient.scala:564)
        at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient.createRecursive(KafkaZkClient.scala:1646)
        at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient.$anonfun$createAclPaths$2(KafkaZkClient.scala:1111)
        at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient.$anonfun$createAclPaths$2$adapted(KafkaZkClient.scala:1111)
        at scala.collection.immutable.HashSet.foreach(HashSet.scala:932)
        at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient.$anonfun$createAclPaths$1(KafkaZkClient.scala:1111)
        at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient.$anonfun$createAclPaths$1$adapted(KafkaZkClient.scala:1109)
        at scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.foreach(IterableOnce.scala:553)
        at scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.foreach$(IterableOnce.scala:551)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:920)
        at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient.createAclPaths(KafkaZkClient.scala:1109)
        at kafka.security.authorizer.AclAuthorizer.configure(AclAuthorizer.scala:169)
        at kafka.admin.AclCommand$AuthorizerService.addAcls(AclCommand.scala:212)
        at kafka.admin.AclCommand$.main(AclCommand.scala:70)
        at kafka.admin.AclCommand.main(AclCommand.scala)
```

**zookeeper.properties (same across all three servers)**

```
tickTime=2000
dataDir=/var/lib/confluent/zookeeper/
clientPort=2181
initLimit=5
syncLimit=2
server.1=kafkaserver1:2888:3888
server.2=kafkaserver2:2888:3888
server.3=kafkaserver3:2888:3888
autopurge.snapRetainCount=3
autopurge.purgeInterval=24


authProvider.1=org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.SASLAuthenticationProvider
authProvider.2=org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.SASLAuthenticationProvider
authProvider.3=org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.SASLAuthenticationProvider
jaasLoginRenew=3600000
requireClientAuthScheme=sasl
```

**server.properties (same across all nodes)**

```
security.inter.broker.protocol=SASL_SSL
ssl.client.auth=required
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=SCRAM-SHA-256
sasl.enabled.mechanisms=SCRAM-SHA-512,PLAIN,SCRAM-SHA-256
ssl.keymanager.algorithm=SunX509
ssl.keystore.location=/opt/confluent-community/certs/kafka.server.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=Password1
ssl.key.password=Password1
ssl.keystore.type=JKS
ssl.protocol=TLS
ssl.trustmanager.algorithm=PKIX
ssl.truststore.location=/opt/confluent-community/certs/kafka.server.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=Password1
ssl.truststore.type=JKS
#authorizer.class.name=kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer
authorizer.class.name=kafka.security.authorizer.AclAuthorizer
super.users=User:admin
zookeeper.set.acl=true
allow.everyone.if.no.acl.found=true
```

**server.properties (Node specific. For simplicity, including only for "kafkaserver1" node)**

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://kafkaserver1:9092,SSL://kafkaserver1:9093,SASL_SSL://kafkaserver1:9094
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://kafkaserver1:9092,SSL://kafkaserver1,SASL_SSL://kafkaserver1:9094
zookeeper.connect=kafkaserver1:2181,kafkaserver2:2181,kafkaserver3:2181
```

**Zookeeper Jaas configuration files (Same across all nodes)**

```
Server {
       org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.DigestLoginModule required
       user_super="Architecture@20"
       user_kafka="Kafka@20";
};
```

**Kaka Jaas configuration file (Same across all nodes)**

```
KafkaServer {
   org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required
   username="admin"
   password="admin-secret";
};

Client {
   org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.DigestLoginModule required
   username="kafka"
   password="kafka-secret"
   user-admin="admin";
};
```

I started zookeeper nodes.. and created admin ACL using the following:

```
$KAFKA_HOME/bin/kafka-configs.sh --zookeeper kafkaserver1:2181,kafkaserver2:2181,kafkaserver3:2181 --alter --add-config 'SCRAM-SHA-256=[password=admin-secret],SCRAM-SHA-512=[password=admin-secret]' --entity-type users --entity-name admin
```

Created demo user as seen below

```
$KAFKA_HOME/bin/kafka-configs.sh --zookeeper kafkaserver1:2181,kafkaserver2:2181,kafkaserver3:2181 --alter --add-config 'SCRAM-SHA-256=[iterations=8192,password=demouser-secret],SCRAM-SHA-512=[password=demouser-secret]' --entity-type users --entity-name demouser
```

So far, everything is working well..

Now, next step is to assign ACL to a demouser by executing the following (This should ideally create a topic and add ACL for a user)

```
$KAFKA_HOME/bin/kafka-acls.sh --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=kafkaserver1:2181,kafkaserver2:2181,kafkaserver3:2181 --add --allow-principal User:demouser --operation Create --operation Describe  --topic demo-topic
```

When I execute the above command, it throws an error mentioned at the start of a thread.

Answer (score 0):

`ssl.client.auth=none` - This should be none in case as you are using **SASL** instead of **SSL**.